# I thought it was hard at school vs I thought school was hard

Tags: phrase-usage

Could you say please there is any difference? Are both sentences common?

> I thought it was hard at school.

> I thought school was hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, these sentences are different.

> I thought school was hard.

This likely means what you're trying to say. In general, overall, school was difficult for the speaker.

> I thought it was hard at school.

I know sometimes English uses the word "it" but isn't actually referring to anything specific (ex. "I thought it was cold at school.") but this isn't one of those times. This is referring to a single, specific thing, which the speaker found difficult in school:

> I'm pretty good at math now, but **I thought it was hard at school**.
>
> Man, making friends as an adult is awful. And **I thought it was hard at school**...

Comment: I agree that **it** could be something specific in the previous sentence, but it could equally be a dummy subject. Without that previous sentence, you cannot say definitely either way.

Comment: @JavaLatte I think this is a very awkward use of the dummy subject, and would not say it at all without context. If somebody said it out of the blue, my most likely response would be "*what* was hard?" If we were talking about your life back then, and then you said it, I'd understand you meant generally - but I also argue that isn't a dummy subject. The topic at hand is already your life in general, and "it" would be referring to that. There's always room for a little subjectivity, I admit, but that's my take on it.

Answer (score 2):

In the first sentence, **it** is a [dummy subject](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/it-and-there-as-dummy-subjects). You can think of it as representing a situation or idea.

> I thought [the situation] was hard at school

There is little difference between the meaning of the two sentences. Both indicate your opinion about school.